# Cassandra-cli could not connect to localhost

Tags: ubuntu, cassandra

I have installed cassandra 1.0.1 stable binary in ubuntu server 11.10 amd64. But, when i try to connect using cassandra-cli with:

> [default@unknown] connect localhost/9160

The system always stuck, and return this

> ...

Any idea?
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the semicolon (;) after each command

Answer (score 0):

As poscaman mentions, you do need a semicolon after every command. But, I recommend connecting using the shell options so you can immediately interact with Cassandra:

```
cassandra-cli -hlocalhost
```

It's also nicer when you arrow-up in Bash (or similar) to use the CLI again.